# Error during composer.phar self-update (Symfony)

Tags: composer-php

Someone can explain me why when I run:

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

I receive this error?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput in phar:///Users/Oscar/Sites/Gamempire/git/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/StreamOutput.php on line 32
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/Oscar/Sites/Gamempire/git/composer.phar:0
PHP   2. require() /Users/Oscar/Sites/Gamempire/git/composer.phar:15
PHP   3. Composer\Console\Application->run() phar:///Users/Oscar/Sites/Gamempire/git/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() phar:///Users/Oscar/Sites/Gamempire/git/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
PHP   5. Composer\Console\Application->doRun() phar:///Users/Oscar/Sites/Gamempire/git/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
PHP   6. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() phar:///Users/Oscar/Sites/Gamempire/git/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:0
PHP   7. include() phar:///Users/Oscar/Sites/Gamempire/git/composer.phar/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:185
PHP   8. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() phar:///Users/Oscar/Sites/Gamempire/git/composer.phar/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:0
PHP   9. include() phar:///Users/Oscar/Sites/Gamempire/git/composer.phar/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:185
```

Comment: Yeah, error.. Delete it and download a new composer.phar

Comment: Done.. but nothing! Same error!

Comment: @OscarFanelli What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It was APC.
Resolved with `php -d "apc.enable_cli=0" composer.phar update`.